# 404 Not Found in incorrect Apache configuration

Tags: apache, virtualhost, orocrm

I have a problem that apache configuration. Here my virtual host setting.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName orocrm.75cl.sg

    DirectoryIndex app.php
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/oro/web
    <Directory  /var/www/html/oro/web>
    # enable the .htaccess rewrites
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

But, when I access to other menus, http://orocrm.75cl.sg/oro/web/app.php/ is always shown in front of the my targeted menu. So, it was shown 404 page. e.g http://orocrm.75cl.sg/oro/web/app.php/magento/cart/. It should be like that http://orocrm.75cl.sg/app.php/magento/cart/

May I know how do I fix this issue.

Comment: Did you restart apache?

Comment: Yes, I already restart.

Comment: Second "stupid" question, but is there no other virtualhost active that could override your settings?

Comment: I only have this setting under /etc/apache2/sites-available/ Host name is 000-default.conf

Comment: @brclz I tried it. But, same result.

Comment: Okay, then let's debug this. What does `sudo apache2ctl -S` (or equivalent) give?

Comment: Have you tried to put `DirectoryIndex app.php` into `<Directory..>?`

Comment: @brclz It was shown VirtualHost configuration:
*:80                   orocrm.75cl.sg (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:1)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex rewrite-map: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33

Comment: @Astasian Yes, I tried it before. But, same result

Comment: Is `dir_module` enabled ? You can check it with `apache2ctl -M`.

Comment: @Astasian It show dir_module (shared)

Comment: So it is turned on.

Comment: You are already specify DocumentRoot with oro/web suffix, so no need to use it again in url.
Try http://orocrm.75cl.sg/app_dev.php

Answer (score 0):

I recall that some versions of Apache come with a pre-configured vhost to point to the welcome.conf and such.

So I would suggest commenting the welcome.conf which is at /etc/httpd or on some distros /etc/apache2 and in those same directories find and remove any installation virtual hosts.

After that you should be free of conflicts as the pre defined virtualhost is like follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/welcome"
```

And that is all I can remember from last time looking at the file.

Enjoy